# Why is it usually easier to perform selection tests in object space?

Tags: graphics, 3d, graphics2d

I'm taking an introductory graphics course, and while I intuitively understand that converting a click or touch into object coordinates will make the math much cleaner, reduce the chances for human error, and potentially make debugging easier, none of these are actually a very good explanation, conceptually, of why object coordinate spaces are used in selection tests, as opposed to simply using world coordinates for the test - rather, they're just observations of what tends to happen when object coordinates are used. So I ask: why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A selection test involves comparing the click coordinates, which you get in window coordinates, against lots and lots of object features, which are represented in object coordinates.

You need to transform them into the same coordinate system in order to do the checks, so you can EITHER transform the one simple click point OR you can transform all the various object features.

Transforming one point or line is just a lot easier that transforming a whole bunch of object features of various types.

Comment: This is extremely helpful! It definitely gives a direct insight into GPU architecture - since they're specifically designed to efficiently do matrix multiplication in parallel, a selection test becomes a matter of assigning each world-to-object transform to a different pipeline's matrix (in order of priority), and then running through the pipeline results to find the first (if any) valid result.

Answer (score 0):

There are cases where the location of a specific object or point may not be known within a world coordinate system, but is known relative to some other coordinate system.

To summarize an example from my course text, consider the idea of two different towns, one using a grid system for its layout, and the other using what I can only describe as the New England we-made-cow-trails-into-roads method. A government employee is tasked with creating a layout of the area which includes them, and in doing so has to convert the two coordinate systems into a third, which encompasses the other two.

Sometimes, using a world atlas just isn't practical to get across the street, and so something much more local (and relevant) is used instead, as it provides much more detail over a much smaller area.

The text also explains that it may be more than simply impractical to use a given coordinate system - it may yield results that are improbable or just plain wrong. This is evidenced in the evolution of the geocentric and heliocentric models of the universe - the distance of the stars from us was calculated with very different results using the two models.

Thinking of my own example, the best that comes to mind would be something like your own internal organs - from the outside, you don't know for sure exactly the shape, size, and structure of each of them, but your own body does. In order to be able to access that information, you need to look inside the body (ideally in a way that doesn't kill you). It's not something that is plainly observable from outside.